# Modifications to Attachments are not reflected in the Inspector when made using Redemption Safe* Objects

Tags: outlook-redemption

I'm using Redemption Safe* Objects to modify the attachments in an email in the ItemSend event.

In some situations we want to add an extra attachment and cancel the sending so that the user can review the changes.  However the changes are not visible in the Inspector window until Outlook has been restarted.  I've tried reopening the Inspector but this is not working.

Is there anyway I can get Outlook to display these changes without restarting Outlook?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to be expected - Outlook does not see changes made with MAPI (and Redemption) until the item in question is completely de-referenced and reopened.

Since adding attachment is not blocked (only reading some of them is), you can make the modifications using the Outlook Object Model.

Comment: We attempt to the use the Outlook Object Model initially but if this fails we fall back on Redemption.  We believe the failures with the OOM are due to another add-in handling the BeforeAttachmentAdd and cancelling our attachment, but as this behaviour is intermittent and our clients have a lot of Add-Ins so we haven't been able to identify which Add-In is causing the issue.

Comment: Is there any other approach we could take that would update the UI? Or is there a better way of troubleshooting VSTO Add-Ins other disabling them until the problem Add-In is identified?

Comment: What is your failing OOM code? How does the failure manifest itself?

Comment: The line that fails is 

_attachment = attachments.Add(filename, OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, Path.GetFileName(filename));

with the Exception

Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments.Add(Object Source, Object Type, Object Position, Object DisplayName)

Comment: The only way I've been able to reproduce this internally is by handling the MailItem BeforeAttachmentAdd event and setting Cancel to true. I'm not sure if this is the only cause of this specific exception through the OOM on this method but haven't been able to identify anything else.